# RecyclerView retrieves data from last position

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with certain data, and each recyclerView item has a button that launch a second activity. 
In the second activity it should display values from the specific item from which button is clicked.
The problem here is that when I press the button from the item in position 0, I have the correct values, but when I press button in position 1, I get the values from position 0:

button at position 2 - displays values from position 1

button at position 3 - displays values from position 2

button at position 4 - displays values from position 3

and so on...

This is the method where I populate the ViewHolder() and the onClick event:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(PicturesHolder viewHolder, Pictures model, final int position) {

                viewHolder.setImage(model.getDownloadURL());
                viewHolder.setLatitude(model.getLatitude());
                viewHolder.setLongitude(model.getLongitude());
                viewHolder.setDateView(model.getDate());

                viewHolder.imageButtonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Launching second activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
                        TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
                        TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
                        String latitude_details = latitude.getText().toString();
                        String longitude_details = longitude.getText().toString();
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUDE,latitude_details);
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUDE,longitude_details);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is the SecondActivity where data is displayed:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String mLatitude = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_LATITUDE);
        String mLongitude = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_LONGITUDE);

        TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_detail);
        TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_detail);

        latitude.setText(mLatitude);
        longitude.setText(mLongitude);

    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if you need more code don't hesitate in asking.
Thank you and greetings!

Comment: The RecyclerView differs from ListViews in several ways, but perhaps the most obvious difference is the way that it deals with views. There are caveats with the view holders and the content contained within. The views are re-used as soon as they're off screen by another row waiting to be rendered. You can monitor this in debug mode or with logging.

Comment: post your `Adapter` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace**

```
 TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
 TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
 String latitude_details = latitude.getText().toString();
 String longitude_details = longitude.getText().toString();
```

**With**

```
String latitude_details = model.getLatitude():
String longitude_details = model.getLongitude();
```

Comment: You should explain why you need to make these changes and *why* `position0` values are loading instead of `position1`

Answer (score 0):

call`sethasstableids(true)` from your recycler View oject in your activity class.

**setHasStableIds** is an optimization hint that you can give to the recycler. You're telling it "when I provide a ViewHolder, its id is unique and will not change."

Answer (score 0):

make your item class override equals and hashcode contract.

```
public abstract class BaseListItem {

    protected int mListItemType;

    public BaseListItem(int itemType) {
        mListItemType = itemType;
    }

    public int getListItemType() {
        return mListItemType;
    }

    public abstract long getId();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof BaseListItem)) {
            return false;
        }

        BaseListItem otherListItem = (BaseListItem) o;
        return otherListItem.getId() == getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Long id = getId();
        return id.hashCode();
    }

}
```